# Como detectar eventos de joystick pelo navegador?

Tags: html5, navegador-de-internet, eventos, jogos

Olá, considerando que eu tenho um joystick conectado e funcionando no meu pc; Como faço para receber eventos dele através do navegador? Isso é possível?

Eu consigo detectar eventos do teclado, só que eu queria que o meu joguinho pudesse ser jogado com o controle (ele é feito em HTML5 mesmo).

Comment: Tem uma tal de GamePad API, não tenho ideia que browsers suportam ela, mas o padrão existe, tem até uma página para vc testar: https://html5gamepad.com/

Comment: Boa [documentação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API). Pega até os eventos quando pressiona um botão do joystick.

Answer (score 2):

O proprio evento `keydown` pega os eventos dos botões de alguns joysticks/controles, no caso poderia enumera-los assim:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      console.log(event.keyCode);
}, true);
```

Assim descobriria cada código de cada tecla, não posso afirmar que todos irão funcionar, nem tenho como testar.

Vale lembrar que existe uma API nativa para isto, a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getGamepads (https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/)

**Mas é experimental**, sendo este o caso nãos há garantias de que irá ser sempre assim ou de que todos navegadores irão suportar de imediato

Com o evento `gamepadconnected` você sabe quando o controle é conectado (exemplo do MDN):

```
window.addEventListener("gamepadconnected", function(e) {
  var gp = navigator.getGamepads()[e.gamepad.index];
  console.log(
    "Gamepad connected at index %d: %s. %d buttons, %d axes.",
    gp.index, gp.id, gp.buttons.length, gp.axes.length
  );
});
```

Dá pra checar também no começo do script quando ele iniciar se todos controles indexados estão conectados sem precisar pressionar nada no botão, lembrando que o controle já estivesse conectado antes da página carregar o evento `gamepadconnected` só será disparado se o usuário mexer um "direcional" (`axis`), então algo como deve resolver para detectar o que estava conectado:

```
var joys = navigator.getGamepads();

for (let i = 0, j = joys.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (joys[i].connected) console.log("Controle conectado: ", i);
}
```

Ressaltando, é experimental. Você também pode checar se o controle for desconectado: https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/#event-gamepaddisconnected

```
window.addEventListener("gamepaddisconnected", function(e) {
  ...
});
```

Não esta documentado se existe evento para detectar quando precisa uma tecla, mas basicamente um `setTimeout` resolveria, algo bem simples como:

```
var listenJoysTimeout, connected = false;

var joys = navigator.getGamepads();

//Verifica se pelo menos um controle esta conectado
for (let i = 0, j = joys.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (joys[i].connected) {
         connected = true;
         break;
    }
}

if (connected) startGame();

window.addEventListener("gamepadconnected", startGame);

window.addEventListener("gamepaddisconnected", function (e) {
    //Só aceita o controle "1"
    if (e.gamepad.index != 0) return;

    if (listenJoysTimeout) clearTimeout(listenJoysTimeout);

    connected = false;
});


function listenJoys(joys)
{
     if (joys[0] && joys[0].connected) {
        let joy = joys[0]; //Aqui pegamos apenas o controle "1", mas seria possivel iterar e verificar todos

        for (let axe of joy.axes) {
            if (axe !== 0) console.log("direção (de -1.0 até 1.0)", axe);
        }

        //Teclas
        for (let button of joy.buttons) {
            if (button.pressed) console.log("Pressionado", button);
        }
     }

     setTimeout(listenJoys, 10, joys);//Executa novamente
}


function startGame(e)
{
    connected = true;

    if (listenJoysTimeout) clearTimeout(listenJoysTimeout);

    listenJoys(joys);
}
```

Nesse exemplo adicionei apenas um controle, mas no geral não é complicado avaliar vários, o que tem que ter em mente é saber qual é qual, mas ai vai além do que foi perguntando, porque vai depender da estrutura desejada do seu jogo.

No https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/#usage-examples fala para usarmos `requestAnimationFrame`, mas usar isto depende de entender o que esta fazendo no seu hipotético jogo, não adianta chegar aqui eu lhe afirmar que isso é uma boa pratica, porque pode ser algo tão simples ou você pode criar algo que trave X situação que no geral pode acabar virando um problema, claro se construiu o seu jogo (animações e frames) com `requestAnimationFrame` então provavelmente já tem noção de como funciona o controle sobre isto, mas chegar em embutir isso diretamente não seria questão de boa pratica, seria como "dirigir" se saber o que é "freio" e "acelerador", então é melhor trabalhar por partes.